# How to push data into widget using dashing dashboard

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dashboard, dashing

I want to push numeric data from a file to my dashboard.

I am using the following .rb file as job for pushing the data

```
SCHEDULER.every '30s' do
var = File.open("/dashing/abhi/sample.txt", "r")
var.each_line do |line|
    puts line
send_event('polarion', { value: var })
end
end
```

but the data is not being displayed in dashboard.

Comment: The indentation in the example is wrong, but I assume that this is only in this post, not in the original code. If the indentation is correct on your original code, you are passing the file `var` instead of the `line` value to the dashing dashboard on `send_event`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be:

```
SCHEDULER.every '30s' do
  var = File.open("/dashing/abhi/sample.txt", "r")
  var.each_line do |line|
    puts line
    send_event('polarion', { value: line })
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still not getting the value pushed to the widget after applying the changes.

Comment: Can you post the content of `puts line`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. the content of /dashing/abhi/sample.txt is  a value which keep on changing. A javacript is in place and the output of the javavscript is a value which will be stored in the file /dashing/abhi/sample.txt .  What I want is to pass the value to the dashboard.

Comment: cat /dashing/abhi/sample.txt
25

Comment: Try changing each_line for each

Comment: Still no luck after replacing each_line with each